# Проверка данных пользователя при авторизации на facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Можно ли как-то выполнить проверку при авторизации пользователя через фейсбук на стороннем сайте действительно ли он там авторизовался, а не передает мне произвольный id.
Может быть, я немного скомкано объяснил, вот тоже самое что мне нужно только во вконтакте, есть ли аналог в фейсбуке?

https://vk.com/dev/openapi_2?f=3.6.%20%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5